# CSS resets aren't removing default browser margin/whitespace around divs

Tags: css, browser

Okay, I have used reset CSS files for quite a while and they have usually worked, but since I have started using CodeIgniter (I don't *think* that has anything to do with it) there has been whitespace around `div`'s that are unaccounted for and persistent across Firefox, Safari and Chrome. I took a screenshot of what I am talking about (the orange arrow is pointing to it):[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Like I said, CSS reset's don't appear to be working.

Comment: Link to the CSS reset file. Please show all related CSS for the object in question, and please show the structure of the object that has the extra whitespace.

Comment: well, you can peruse the document in question here: `http://southshift.com/portfolio`

Comment: see my answer now and let me know it i am lagging anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display: block;` to the img it will remove the extra white space check the result

and i also try the [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) and [mozilla webdeveloper tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/#) that they are great tool

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I rarely deal with `<img>`, so it's been a while. ha.